# Upgrade gcc to 7.3 after installing CUDA9 using gcc 6.5

Tags: 18.04, gcc, cuda

I've installed CUDA9 strictly following [this post](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/470a57e5c9fc9ab9f9c4e042d5941a40). And to do so, I have to downgrade gcc from 7.3 to 6.5. I'm wondering if I can upgrade gcc back to 7.3? Will this cause any problem? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
The following are my gcc and g++ version.
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you followed the linked instructions correctly, you didn't "downgrade" your system's versions of gcc/g++ at all, instead you just installed gcc-6/g++-6 in addition to the default versions and created symlinks from them to `/usr/local/cuda/bin`. What do `gcc --version` and/or `g++ --version` say?

Comment: Hi, @steeldriver. I've updated the gcc and g++ versions. The instructions seem only to setup symlinks for gcc and g++. I'm wondering if i can change it back without causing any troubles

Comment: Hmm... I missed the part of the instructions where it suggests putting `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin` at the head of your `PATH` - I don't see why that should be necessary TBH, if you hadn't done that then (outside of CUDA), `gcc` should continue to find gcc 7.3 first

Comment: I've done that...Is this the reason why `gcc` is 7.3? I thought it was because `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc`...